# Reversing first and last name - code not printing

Tags: python, printing

I'm trying to reverse names given by the user, for example Herbert von Knass should be written as von Knass, Herbert. I've run into a brick wall now as my code doesn't print anything despite the print command, where am I going wrong? This is my code:

```
def reverse_name(name):
    if len(name) == 2:
        first = name.split()[0]
        last = name.split()[-1]
        print(f"{last}, {first}")
    if len(name) == 3:
        first = name.split()[0]
        last = name.split()[-2] + " " + name.split()[-1]
        print(f"{last}, {first}")
    if len(name) == 1:
        print(f"{name}")
def main():
    name = input()
    reverse_name(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What is `'Herbert von Knass'`'s `len`?

Answer (score 2):

You should check for `len(name.split())` in your conditionals as now you're checking the string length and not the word count.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the usage of len(). Some basic change could look like this:

```
def reverse_name(name):
    name_parts = name.split(" ")
    reverse_name = name

    if len(name_parts) == 2:
        first = name_parts[0]
        last = name_parts[1]
        reverse_name = f"{last}, {first}"
    elif len(name_parts) > 2:
        first = name.split()[0]
        last = name.split()[-2] + " " + name.split()[-1]
        reverse_name = f"{last}, {first}"

    print(reverse_name)
    return reverse_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `len` on string which does return its' number of characters, consider that

```
print(len("Herbert von Knass"))
```

gives output

```
17
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answers re your conditionals, and using a `.split()`, suggesting the following code in your function to simplify your conditions:

```
def reverse_name(name):
    name_parts = name.split(" ")
    first = name_parts[0]
    last = " ".join(name_parts[1:])
    print(f"{last}, {first}") if last else print(first)
```

If a single name is entered, there will not be a last name (`last` is falsy), so only the first name (`first`) is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using len() for finding len of full string, I think first you split then find len() like below then it works .

```
    def reverse_name(name):
        l=name.split(" ")
        name_len=len(l)
        if len(name) == 2:
            first = name.split()[0]
            last = name.split()[-1]
            print(f"{last}, {first}")
        if len(name) == 3:
            first = name.split()[0]
            last = name.split()[-2] + " " + name.split()[-1]
            print(f"{last}, {first}")
        if len(name) == 1:
            print(f"{name}")
    def main():
        name = input()
        reverse_name(name)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```